# PHP Card swiping for a website's access

Tags: php, web, registration

I want to implement card swiping for a website's access and to identify the customer's count of visit. This website is controlled by the staff of an airport lounge in front of the customers and the staff ask for the swipe there after customer does that.

I want add some numbers so the server can understand the customer's visit count e.g: for the first visit he/she will see a page asking for the payment, after couple of days/second time he/she swipe so the server understand his second visit and land the customer to second visit page.

Comment: Urgent is a very subjective concept, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume (as we must as you supply no info) that you have a `Customer` table, you could have a `count` column which is incremented with each purchase / visit / card swipe, thereby tracking the number of visits. You could then retrieve this information from the table each time the card is swiped, and display it on the screen to the Server.